# How to fix the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String"

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to create a table with quantities and price of the provided input items.

package new.learnprogramming;

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
String apples = "Apples";
int appleQuantity = 8;
int applePrice = 400;
String oranges = "Oranges";
int orangeQuantity = 10;
int orangePrice = 150;

String column1Heading = "Fruits";
String column2Heading = "Quantity";
String column3Heading = "Price";

System.out.printf("%10s %10s %5s%n", column1Heading, column2Heading, column3Heading);
System.out.printf("%10s %8d %11d cents%n", apples, appleQuantity , currencyFormat.format(applePrice));
System.out.printf("%11s %8d %10d cents%n", oranges, orangeQuantity, currencyFormat.format(orangePrice));


}
}
```

I am trying to get the output as:

Fruits   Quantity  Price
Apples   8        $400.00 cents
Oranges  10       $150.00 cents

But, the output is coming up as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2938)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2892)
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: Use `%11s` and `%10s` for the third column, instead of `%11d` and `%10d`.  You're putting strings there, but `d` is for integers.

Comment: Thanks, Kareem your solution resolved my problem.

Comment: You are doing all your formatting twice. Make up your mind. Either use `Formatters` *or* `printf()`. Not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NumberFormat.format(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(long)) returns a `String` (and the format for a `String` is `%s`, like your first column). Like,

```
System.out.printf("%10s %8d %11s cents%n", apples, 
        appleQuantity, currencyFormat.format(applePrice));
System.out.printf("%11s %8d %10s cents%n", oranges, 
        orangeQuantity, currencyFormat.format(orangePrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply fix format specifiers. %d is for decimal.

```
        System.out.printf("%10s %10s %5s%n", column1Heading, column2Heading, column3Heading);
        System.out.printf("%10s %8d %11s cents%n", apples, appleQuantity , currencyFormat.format(applePrice));
        System.out.printf("%11s %8d %10s cents%n", oranges, orangeQuantity, currencyFormat.format(orangePrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormat.format()` ([see this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double))) returns a `String`, not an `int`/`long`/`double`/or similar. You're format is expecting the latter because you are using `%d`, but you should be using `%s` so that it properly expects a `String`.